# How to post post to a user wall as a facebook fan page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'd like my app to post on users wall as a page that I own.

How can I do that?

I tried this:

```
$facebook->api("/<USER_ID>/feed/", "post", array(
            'from' => array('id' => <MY PAGE'S ID>),
            'message' => 'TEST',
        'access_token' => <MY PAGE'S TOKEN>,
));
```

But I received the following error:
OAuthException: (#200) Posts where the actor is a page cannot also include a target_id

Any idea to help me?

Answer (score 2):

you cannot post to user wall as a page you need to create a application and post as an application but in post you can link with your page  and then you can post on user wall

```
$stram = $facebook->api("/$user/feed", 'post', array(
                'message' => "abcdef ",
                'link'    => 'http://facebook.com/yourpage',
                'picture' => 'http://abc.com/yourpagelogo.jpg',
                'name'    => 'Stackoverflow',
                'description'=> 'hu ha hu ha hu ha hu ha'
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't post to user's wall as a page. Only users can post to users' walls.